# Cron не выполняет команды rm и find

Tags: linux, debian, cron, crontab, find

Я открываю `crontab -e`, указываю команду:
`* * * * * /bin/bash -lc "rm -rf /tmp/mc-$USER/"`

> Все команды, которые я пытаюсь выполнить через cron рабочие, я их всех потестил в bash'e

Жду минуту - файлы не удаляются.
Еще я попробовал так же через find:
`* * * * * /bin/bash -lc "find /tmp/mc-$USER/ -delete"`
Тот же эффект, файлы не удаляет :(

> Cron другие мои команды выполняет! Например такая команда рабочая:
>   * * * * * /bin/bash -lc "echo test > ~/corologtest"

Я чекнул лог крона, команды выполнялись `sudo grep CRON /var/log/syslog`:

```
Aug 21 10:51:01 vm2 CRON[7505]: (mcraft) CMD (/bin/bash -lc "find /tmp/mc-$USER/ -delete")
Aug 21 10:52:01 vm2 CRON[7522]: (mcraft) CMD (/bin/bash -lc "find /tmp/mc-$USER/ -delete")
Aug 21 10:53:01 vm2 CRON[7535]: (mcraft) CMD (/bin/bash -lc "find /tmp/mc-$USER/ -delete")
Aug 21 10:54:01 vm2 CRON[7548]: (mcraft) CMD (/bin/bash -lc "find /tmp/mc-$USER/ -delete")
Aug 21 10:55:01 vm2 CRON[7574]: (mcraft) CMD (/bin/bash -lc "find /tmp/mc-$USER/ -delete")
```

Система `cat /etc/*release*`:

```
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="8"
VERSION="8 (jessie)"
ID=debian
HOME_URL="http://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.debian.org/support"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"
You have new mail in /var/mail/mcraft
```

Система `uname -a`:

```
Linux vm2 3.16.0-6-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.57-2 (2018-07-14) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: *Все команды, которые я пытаюсь выполнить через cron рабочие, я их всех потестил в bash'e* От имени той учётной записи, от которой они выполняются cron-ом?

Answer (score 2):

man 5 crontab:

`The value string is not parsed for environmental substitutions or replacement of variables, thus lines like`

```
PATH = $HOME/bin:$PATH
```

`will not work as you might expect.`

При этом в окружении, в котором исполняются задачи, переменная $USER не установлена.

Желаемое можно получить следуюшим образом:

```
* * * * * /bin/bash -lc "find /tmp/mc-`whoami`/ -delete"
```

или

```
USER=youruser
* * * * * /bin/bash -lc "find /tmp/mc-$USER/ -delete"
```

Кроме того, cron обычно в сетапах по умолчанию отсылает локальному пользователю письмо с stdout и stderr выполненной задачи, если они были не пусты, по которым в данном случае можно было сделать предположения. Посмотрите в /var/mail/$USER

Answer (score 0):

укажите полный путь к выполняемым командам rm или find

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена, дело в том, что $USER переменной нет в cron. но юзера можно получить так:

```
`id -u -n`
```

Вот рабочая команда:

```
/bin/bash -lc "find /tmp/mc-`id -u -n`/ -delete"
```